# Total Supply reading in as zero for deployed Ether Token contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

i am kind of new to solidity development and while following up this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyoFT4QkoL4 tutorial by DAPP University on how to make your own ERC-20 Token, I ran into some Supply issue.
Since i didnt copy paste code from github but rather took the initiative of understanding the code and re writing the whole contract by myself. Whenever I add my token in metamask it shows me 0 value and when i check further i get this error =>
**"Total Supply reading in as zero for deployed Ether Token contract"**
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xc4111C1Be1fEbb587ee7Fa8E077fa9C636eE5d50
[the above link was suggested to me by metamask to see the full error]

Here is my [Etherscan][2]

Can someone help me troubleshoot?
Here is the code =>

````
//Day3

pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract Token{
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint256 public decimal;
    uint256 public TotalSupply;
    mapping (address => uint256) public Balance;
    mapping (address => mapping(address => uint256)) public SpendingAllowance; //My address => (spenderAddr => SpendingAmount)

    event TransferEvent(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event AllowanceEvent(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint _decimal){
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimal = _decimal;
        TotalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000;
        Balance[msg.sender] = TotalSupply;  //giving myself all the supply hahahahaha!

    }




    //dummy transac function to check all the requirements and then call the main transaction function
    function dummytransfer(address _to, uint _value) external returns (bool){

        require(Balance[msg.sender] >= _value, "Insufficient funds to send ://"); //check my funds
        require(_to != address(0), "Invalid address"); //check receiver address
        Realtransfer(msg.sender,_to,_value); //call real transaction function
        return true; //return true
    }

    function Realtransfer(address owner, address receiver, uint amount) internal{
        Balance[owner] = Balance[owner] - amount; //deduct the amount from my(owner) balance
        Balance[receiver] = Balance[receiver] + amount; //add the amount to the receiver balance
        emit TransferEvent(owner,receiver,amount); //emit the Transfer Event
    }

    //Approve some tokens to the dapp's address [ex=> Uniswap]
    function Approve(address _spender, uint _value) external returns(bool){
        require(_spender != address(0), "Invalid Address");
        SpendingAllowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit AllowanceEvent(msg.sender,_spender,_value);
        return true;
    }

    //Allow the actual transfer for dapps
    //_from is basically dapp's address
    function AllowanceTransfer(address _from, address _to, uint amount) external returns(bool){
        require(Balance[_from] >= amount); //check if dapp got enough juice
        require(SpendingAllowance[_from][msg.sender] >= amount); //check if that much token spending is allowed
        SpendingAllowance[_from][msg.sender] = SpendingAllowance[_from][msg.sender] - amount; //deduct the dapp's balance
        Realtransfer(_from,_to,amount); //call the real transaction ;)
        return true;
    }



  
}```


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyoFT4QkoL4
  [2]: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xaF46D502E61C8EED18D796a5cB5584ada779464a#code
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a storage variable with the name `totalSupply` and assign it from the constructor.

```
contract Token {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint256 public decimals; 
    
    // Total supply storage variable
    uint256 public totalSupply;   
    
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping(address => uint256)) public SpendingAllowance;

    event TransferEvent(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event AllowanceEvent(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint _decimals){
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals = _decimals;
        totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000;
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply; 
    }

    //.....
}
```

Comment: Hey @Igor Senych i actually tried that too but no luck ://
I have updated the code above please check thanks

Comment: Make it `totalSupply` instead of `TotalSupply`, and `decimals` instead of `decimal`.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out!
ill check and fix and retry :)

Comment: This is the [ERC20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) description, please read it. The names in your contract must be the same, and the case of letters matters.